# How to create editText in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I'd like to create editable textfield in fragment, which after close or stop of app would be saved. But there's something wrong in line with `return notatki;` I already have this:

```
public class DetailFragment2 extends Fragment {

    private EditText notatki;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("Test", "hello");


    }     
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details2, parent, false);
        notatki = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        notatki.setText(settings.getString("value", ""));
        return view;
    }  
    @Override
    public void onStop( ){
        super.onStop();
        if(notatki.getText() != null) {
            SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("value", notatki.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

When I change `return notatki;` to `return view;` it works until the stop of app, when I wanted to save content of editText but it isn't saving anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
private EditText notatki;
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details2, parent, false);
        notatki = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        notatki.setText(settings.getString("value", ""));

  return view; // return view here instead of notaki
}
```

You have already declared EditText as a class member

```
 private EditText notatki;
```

So just initialize it in `onCreateView`.

Comment: Thank you, I laso change it back to `return view` and everything is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
EditText notatki = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

to

```
notatki = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

because if you declare it again in your `onCreateView` it will shadow the global one and you will get it null in `onStop`

Answer (score 0):

Try This....

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details2, parent, false);
    EditText notatki = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
    notatki.setText(settings.getString("value", ""));
    return view;
}
```

Comment: `Try This...?` why not explain it a bit?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right but the problem is that you should return the parent view from `onCreateView` and not the EditText instance `notatki`

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details2, parent, false);
        ....
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private EditText etext;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondfragment,container,false);
        etext = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        return v;
```